# C# .NET x86/x64 which project determines platform?

Tags: c#, .net, x86-64, platform

I have the following situation in my visual studio project:

- assemby C
- project A -> class library **Any CPU** (references assembly C)
- project B -> windows application **x86** (references project A)

In this configuration, what determines what platform assembly C will use?

1. project B which is the startup project --> assembly C will run x86
2. project A which is the project who directly references assembly C --> assembly C will run x86 or x64 depending on platform

1 or 2?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The startup assembly determines which platform is used. If the startup assembly is built as "Any CPU" it will run on the platform the OS runs on.

(in other words, 1)

Comment: +1. Exactly. The executable determines, the rest has to follow (or throws exceptions).

Answer (score -2):

It depends on what Assembly C was compiled for target wise. The other projects do not affect it's bitness in any way shape or form. This type of setup with mixed targets could cause lots of issues.

Since B is the Application it will run as x86. If you are on an x64, Project A will fail to load because A will try to run as x64 and an x86 Application cannot load x64 dll's

If you run it on x86 machine, than Project A will also run x86 and will load correctly.

Comment: Nice, not wrong, bu totally ignoring the question about how it WILL LOAD. Not hat issues arise out of it. And assemblies (i.e. non exes) have no say in that.

Comment: Project A will load just fine because it is AnyCPU.  In a 32-bit process, an AnyCPU class library will be JITted to x86 code.

Comment: But the executable in this case is Project B, so my answer is right I think